# Stop Words Filtering for some documents 

Tags: php, mysql, database

I confused how to filter words of some documents. I have to checked out the documents one by one. for example from tb_tokens :

```
======================================================================
| tokens_id | tokens_word | tokens_freq|  sentence_id |  document_id |
======================================================================
|     1     |      A      |      1     |       0      |       1      |
|     2     |      B      |      1     |       0      |       1      |
|     3     |      C      |      1     |       1      |       1      |
|     4     |      D      |      1     |       0      |       2      |
|    ...    |             |            |              |              |
======================================================================
```

I have to remove all words that appear on a list od common words like  “and”, “the”, etc.. The list recorded in table tb_stopword and then remove words that occurr in large number across most documents that appear on a list recorded in tb_term table.

the function cekStopWord :

```
function cekStopWord ($word) {
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT stoplist_word FROM tb_stopword where stoplist_word = '$word' ");
   $row = mysql_fetch_row($query);
   if($row > 0) {
        return true;
   } else {
        return false;
   }        
}
```

And the similar function for the second process (remove words that occurr in large number across most documents)

```
function cekTerm ($word) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT term_word FROM tb_term where term_word = '$word' ");
```

I confused how to process in every documents. I tried to call by doc_id, but it doesnt work. and here's my code :

```
//$doc_id is a variable that save array of document_id
$query = mysql_query('SELECT tokens_word, sentence_id, document_id FROM tb_tokens WHERE document_id IN (' . implode(",", $doc_id) . ')') or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $word[$row['document_id']][$row['sentence_id']] = $row['tokens_word'];
}
foreach ($word as $doc_id => $words){
    $cekStopWord = cekStopWord($words);
    $cekTerm     = cekTerm($words);
    if((preg_match("/^[A-Z, 0-9]/", $words))&& (!$cekStopWord) && (!$cekTerm) ){
          $q = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tb_tagging VALUES ('','$words','','$sentence_id','$doc_id') ");
```

and also how to use preg_match in array ?
thank you so much :)

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @vascowhite will do sir.. but, would you help me please to solve my problem here.. ?

Comment: Edit your code to use PDO and prepared statements and I may be able to help, but I won't help you to learn bad practices.